# Testing isinstance(PosixPath) using pytest with pyfakefs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyfakefs

In my code, I test if `config_location` is an instance of `PosixPath` or `None`:

```py
if isinstance(self.config_location, (PosixPath, type(None))):
    ...
```

This works fine when run with the normal python interpreter, but fails during my pytest tests using pyfakefs, as the pyfakefs object is of type `pyfakefs.fake_pathlib.FakePathlibModule.PosixPath`. The obvious solution here would be to import pyfakefs into the tested code and add `pyfakefs.fake_pathlib.FakePathlibModule.PosixPath` to the isinstance tuple, but this approach seems very clunky to me.

There has to be a better way ?

Comment: Check the limitations for pyfakefs: http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/intro.html#:~:text=the%20actual%20user.-,Limitations,-%C2%B6

Comment: It depends on your goal. If you just want to check if the object is of a path type, you could check for `PurePath` instead - both `PosixPath` implementations derive from that. Generally it is not considered good practice to use `isinstance`, but I don't know if there is a better way in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for `PurePath` instead works.